# How project structure is displayed in eclipse, how manage it?

Tags: eclipse, maven, spring-mvc

I have Spring-MVC application. Files like: **.project, .classpath**, I dont keep in repository, I generate it by eclipse during import (`eclipse import maven project`).
Sometimes in `Project Explorer` View, project looks like:

[image]

And sometimes like below:

[image]

Can I manage this, how? I prefere second view, how convert first to second view? On screens are Eclipse Juno and Kepler, both have the same plugins installed (mostly).

Answer (score 0):

In the first screenshot, the SRC/  folder is not a source folder, whereas in the second the folders SRC/main/Java, SRC/main/resources...  are sources folder and not the SRC/.A right click on the SRC/ and then Build path, set a source folder should
fix that in the first image. In the second, remove from build path SRC/* and then do as above.